# Python: git remote add -f origin in Dulwich

Tags: python, gitpython, dulwich

i want execute

`git remote add -f origin <repo>`

with dulwich. however, i couldn't find something in this direction.

Knows somebody a solution or an alternative in gitpython?

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Don't the [dulwich docs on remote repos](https://www.dulwich.io/docs/tutorial/remote.html) show you what to do?

Comment: My code doesn't work. I get the error socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: from dulwich.repo import Repo
    from dulwich.server import DictBackend, TCPGitServer

    repo = dulwich.repo.Repo.init('remote', mkdir=True)
    backend = DictBackend({'/': repo})
    dul_server = TCPGitServer(backend, 'git://server.com/file.git', 0)
    threading.Thread(target=dul_server.serve).start()
    server_address, server_port = dul_server.socket.getsockname()
    client = dulwich.client.TCPGitClient(server_address.encode('ascii'), server_port)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dulwich *master*, you can use the dulwich.porcelain.remote_add method:

```
from dulwich import porcelain
porcelain.remote_add('origin', 'http://github.com/git/git')
```

In older versions (that don't have porcelain.remote_add) you can use something like:

```
from dulwich.repo import Repo
c = Repo('.').get_config()
c.set(('remote "origin"', ), "url", "http://github.com/git/git") 
c.write_to_path()
```